# Stay logged in with Facebook Connect and iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I use Facebook Connect (and the OmniAuth gem) for authenticating users on my Rails website. On my desktop - users can stay logged in across browser sessions. But accessing the same site from within my iPhone - I can log in via FB Connect - but when my browser session ends - so too does my logged in user. Especially annoying on an iPhone because it does take a while to go through the whole connect process.

I assume it has to do with cookies not surviving browser sessions. Is there something I can do to keep my users logged in when using their iPhone browsers?